What is(How to know) the relationship between network connections?
I have the following network set up:
PC------modem-----ISP
The modem is working in bridging mode so I need to create a broadband connection on my PC.
There are quite a few networking connections in Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections:
"Ethernet 2" corresponds to the physical NIC on the PC, "Broadband Connection" corresponds to the broadband connection I created, and other connections are created by some VPN software.
Since these connections are all shown there, they seem to be in equal status. But they are actually not because some use the service of others so they must be on top of others. For example, the broadband connection must be using the physical NIC to transmit data to the modem so it seems to be on top of the  "Ethernet 2" connection. The connections created by VPN must be using the broadband connection(or the "Ethernet 2" connection?) to transmit data so they should be on top of the broadband connection(or the "Ethernet 2" connection?)
Using "route print -4", I can see which IP packet is sent to which network connection. The problem is how to know where to go next when the IP packets are going out of a network connection. For example, when the packets go out of a connection created by VPN, where do they go? Do they go to the broadband connection, or the "Ethernet 2" connection?
And I cannot see a data path between the broadband connection and the "Ethernet 2" connection. So, suppose I have two physical NICs each of which connects to a different modem provided by different ISP, how can I know which physical NIC to go when the data go out of the broadband connection? When I created the broadband connection, it did not ask me to choose a physical NIC(it only asked me for an account name/password gotten from an ISP).

For example, when the packets go out of a connection created by VPN, where do they go? They go to the VPN program, and the program encapsulate it as e.g. a UDP datagram payload, and send it out of this "broadband connection" interface, which is probably a "product" of PPPoE, which I'm not really familiar with but I suppose it is at least in some way similar to VPN. See perhaps https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunneling_protocol.

@TomYan Suppose a packet with ip1 as the destination ip is sent into the connection created by the VPN according to the route table, then when it is going out of the VPN program, is its destination ip changed? If not changed, the ip packet will be sent to the VPN connection again according to the route table, and this seems an endless loop. I know sing-box creates a default route with the least metric 0 so that every packet goes to the connection created by it. But I don't know where the packets go after they are out of sing-box.

is its destination ip changed No, as I mentioned, the whole packet end up being encapsulated in another packet. The "outer" packet header would have the "new" destination IP address (presumably the "remote" IP address of a VPN server). The VPN program normally replace the original default route on system by some means if the VPN server is supposed to act as an "Internet gateway" for the client, and it will also make sure by some means that the encapsulated traffics will not use this new default route it added. (What the means are exactly is VPN program- and could be even OS-specific.)
